# Find and Replace Single Digit numbers in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to locate single-digit numbers in MS Word (1-9) and replace it with word i.e. (1 = one, 2 = two). The current code replaces two-digit numbers and above. As of now, the only solution I can think of is to add spaces before and after the specific number but it is not that accurate.

Here is the code that I am using. TIA

```
Sub Single_Number()

Dim myDict: Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

myDict("[1]{1}") = "one"
myDict("[2]{1}") = "two"
myDict("[3]{1}") = "three"
myDict("[4]{1}") = "four"
myDict("[5]{1}") = "five"
myDict("[6]{1}") = "six"
myDict("[7]{1}") = "seven"
myDict("[8]{1}") = "eight"
myDict("[9]{1}") = "nine"
Dim msword As Document, xWarp As Integer
For Each msword In Documents
msword.Activate
For myLoop = 0 To myDict.Count - 1
    change_words myDict.Keys()(myLoop), myDict.Items()(myLoop)
Next
Next msword
End Sub

Function change_words(ByVal findWord, ByVal replaceWord)
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
        xWarp = wdFindContinue
    Else
        xWarp = wdFindStop
    End If
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = findWord
        .Replacement.Text = replaceWord
        .Forward = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = xWarp
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Your code will likely work better if you do a wildcard search for a single number not followed by another number  e.g. the search string should be "[0-9][!0-9]"

Answer (score 0):

Using the follow on string wasn't quite the best answer.  The code below does the trick If and only if you only want to search in the main content of the document and your single digit numbers are preceded by a Space. If you are in the unfortunate position of having a single digit as the first character in a paragraph this code won't catch that issue.  I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader as to how to modigy the () to include things such a paragraph markers.

The code below has been tested with

```
This 1 is 2 some 8 text 9. This is some7 more6 5 text
```

which is correctly converted as

```
This One is Two some Eight text Nine. This is some7 more6 Five text
```

This is the code

```
Sub ReplaceSingleNumbersWithText()

' Set up a search term for a single digit where the single digit is preceded
' by a space and followed by a character that is not a number or a letter
Const DIGIT_SEARCH                      As String = "( )([XXX]{1})([!0-9a-zA-Z])"

Dim myDigitAsWord                       As Variant
Dim mySearchDoc                         As Word.Document
Dim myIndex                             As Long
Dim myFindText                          As String
Dim myReplaceText                       As String

    myDigitAsWord = Split("Zero,One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine", ",")

    For Each mySearchDoc In Word.Application.Documents

        With mySearchDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)

            With .Find

                .ClearFormatting
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchWildcards = True

            End With

            For myIndex = 0 To UBound(myDigitAsWord)

                myFindText = Replace(DIGIT_SEARCH, "XXX", CStr(myIndex))
                myReplaceText = "\1" & myDigitAsWord(myIndex) & "\3"
                .Find.Execute FindText:=myFindText, replacewith:=myReplaceText, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

            Next

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```